# Using SwapMouseButton( TRUE ); to allow right click dragging of a window

Tags: c++, windows, c++builder-2007

I am required to somehow allow a window to be moved using a right click drag option. I have done this via some sneeky code which I don't really like but it works.

Currently I am trapping the WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN message and setting a bool to say that I am in move mode, resetting this variable when the WM_NCRBUTTONUP is received. While in moving mode I am checking for WMNCMouseMove and moving the form myself. As this is slow to keep up with quick mouse movements I also set a timer to do the same using the GetCursorPos.

I have recently discovered the SwapMouseButton function and this does exactly what I want. However there is a but! I need to swap it conditionally and only when the user has right clicked the CAPTION area of a window.

So I swap the mouse buttons round when I receive the WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN and reset on WM_NCRBUTTONUP. However this will work on subsequent clicks provided the WM_NCRBUTTONUP never reset it. This I think is because the clicking event has already happened so is to late to swap which is why it works for subsequent right click hits but not the right click and drag which caused the swapping of the mouse!

Can anybody see a way around this. Baring in mind that I need the left click functionality for the close, minimize, maximise buttons etc. Right click onyl for the moving!

Please Help!!!!!

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manually tracking the mouse or swapping the buttons, there is an easier way - in response to `WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN`, simply put the window into a move mode natively by sending it a special `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message, then it will handle all the hard work of dragging for you, eg:

```
const WPARAM MOUSE_MOVE = SC_MOVE + 2;

case WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN:
{
    POINT pt; 
    GetCursorPos(&pt); 
    SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCRBUTTONUP, 0, MAKELPARAM(pt.x, pt.y));
    SendMessage(Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, MOUSE_MOVE, MAKELPARAM(pt.x, pt.y));
    break;
}
```

See [Q114593](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/114593/) for more details.

**Update:** I wasn't able to get `WM_SYSCOMMAND` to work with right-clicking (it works great when left-clicking on child controls, though).  I think the OS is doing some internally processing that simply makes it impossible to work correctly.  So I went with the approach of intercepting mouse movements to move the window manually, making it operate correctly with fast mouse movements without the use of a timer by using `SetCapture()` instead:

```
bool RightButton_CanMove = false;
bool RightButton_WindowMoved = false;
POINTS LastPoint;

void __fastcall TForm1::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    switch( Message.Msg )
    {
        case WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN:
            LastPoint = MAKEPOINTS(Message.LParam);
            RightButton_CanMove = true;
            RightButton_WindowMoved = false;
            SetCapture(Handle);
            Message.Result = 0;
            return;

        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
            if( (Message.WParam & MK_RBUTTON) && (RightButton_CanMove) )
            {
                POINT CurPoint;
                GetCursorPos(&CurPoint);

                SetWindowPos(Handle, NULL, Left + (CurPoint.x - LastPoint.x), Top + (CurPoint.y - LastPoint.y), 0, 0, SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
                LastPoint.x = CurPoint.x;
                LastPoint.y = CurPoint.y;

                RightButton_WindowMoved = true;
            }
            break;

        case WM_RBUTTONUP:
            if( RightButton_CanMove )
            {
                RightButton_CanMove = false;
                ReleaseCapture();

                if( RightButton_WindowMoved )
                {
                    RightButton_WindowMoved = false;
                    Message.Result = 0;
                    return;
                }
            }
            break;
    }

    TForm::WndProc(Message);
}
```

The code differentiates between right-click and right-move operations.  If the user right-clicks the mouse without moving it, the default popup menu is allowed to appear normally.  If the user holds down the right mouse button down and moves the window around, the default popup is not displayed when the user releases the right button.

Comment: This is a much better way but doesn't seem to work-code is as follows: void __fastcall TForm2::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
     switch ( Message.Msg )
     {
         case WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN:
         {
             const WPARAM MOUSE_MOVE = SC_MOVE + 2;
             POINT pt;
             GetCursorPos(&pt);
             SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCRBUTTONUP, 0, MAKELPARAM(pt.x, pt.y));
             SendMessage(Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, MOUSE_MOVE, MAKELPARAM(pt.x, pt.y));
             break;
         }
         default:
         {
             break;
         }
     }
     TForm::WndProc(Message);
}

Comment: You are passing the WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN message to the inherited WndProc() for default processing, after sending the WM_NCRBUTTONUP and WM_SYSCOMMAND messages. Trying taking that step out.

Comment: Hi, Not passing the WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN to the inherited WndProc doesn't solve the problem. Do you have any other ideas? I am using a framework for this (Borland C++ Builder). Does this make a difference? Thanks again!

Comment: Also why in your example do you set the WPARAM to SC_MOVE + 2? If I just send SC_MOVE as the param in the WM_SYSCOMMAND then I get a funny cursor, still no moving action though?

Comment: Did you read the article I pointed you to? `SC_MOVE + 2` has special meaning to Windows. I also use C++Builder, I will try posting a working example shortly.

Comment: Hi I have read the article thank you. I have created working examples for moving the form by selecting the client area with left mouse click etc, this is not a problem. The trouble is trying to do it using the right mouse button as described. The only way I have managed to do it is via the swap mouse button (Problem outlined in this post) or moving the form myself.. The example that you have posted would work for other SYSCOMMANDS such as maxamise. I think Windows has a real problem with right click moving. A working example would be AMAZING as I have literraly tried for weeks with this!Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for spending the time to write that!! That works really nicely. I am really please that I can ditch the timer. Really neat solution that I will be keeping and analysing to learn what has been done! Thanks again, I have lost weeks on this, but now it all seems worthwhile!